# Cakephp 3 muffin/trash soft-delete plugin when restoreTrash show error "Books not found"

Tags: cakephp, plugins

I make a soft-delete using muffin/trash CakePHP 3.* plugins. I successfully **soft-deleted** my book but when I try to **restore** I get the following error:

> Record not found in table "books"

This is my controller file (BooksController.php) :

```php
    public function restoreBook($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'put']);
        $book = $this->Books->get($id);
        if ($this->Books->restoreTrash($book)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The book has been restored.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The book could not be restored. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
```

This is my view file (Books/index.ctp) here I call my restoreBook function :

```php
    <td class="actions">
                        <?php if (!$book->deleted) : ?>
                        <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $book->id]) ?>
                        <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $book->id]) ?>
    
                        <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $book->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $book->id)]) ?>
    
                        <?php endif; ?>
    
                        <?php if ($book->deleted) : ?>
                        <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Restore'), ['action' => 'restoreBook', $book->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to restore # {0}?', $book->id)]) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
    
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data already deleted (soft-delete), we need to add 'withTrashed' to find back the data :

```
public function restoreBook($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'put']);
        //must add 'withTrashed' to find the deleted data
        $book = $this->Books->find('withTrashed')->where(['id =' => $id])->first();
        if ($this->Books->restoreTrash($book)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The book has been restored.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The book could not be restored. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
```